# How many unique keys does my data.table have?

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table`, how do I find the number of unique keys it contains?

```
library(data.table)
z <- data.table(id=c(1,2,1,3),key="id")
length(unique(z$id))
==> 3
```

The problem is that `unique` is *quadratic* in general, but, since keys in a `data.table` are sorted,  it should be possible to find the number of unique keys in the `data.table` in *linear* time.

Comment: @Arun: hash tables are `O(N)` _worst case_ (constant expectation) so we get `O(N^2)` worst case.

Comment: @sds, that would happen if all your values are dumped on to the same bucket - that must be a terrible hash function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
sum(Negate(duplicated)(z$id))
```

z$id remains sorted, so duplicated can work faster on it:

```
bigVec <- sample(1:100000, 30000000, replace=TRUE)
system.time( sum(Negate(duplicated)(bigVec)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  8.161   0.475   8.690 

bigVec <- sort(bigVec)
system.time( sum(Negate(duplicated)(bigVec)) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    2.09    2.10
```

But I just checked and length(unique()) works faster on sorted vectors as well...

So maybe there is some kind of checking if the vector is sorted going on (which can be done in a linear time). To me this doesn't look to be quadratic:

```
system.time( length(unique(bigVec)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.583   0.664 

bigVec <- sort(sample(1:100000, 20000000, replace=TRUE))
system.time( length(unique(bigVec)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   1.290   1.242 

bigVec <- sort(sample(1:100000, 30000000, replace=TRUE))
system.time( length(unique(bigVec)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   1.655   1.715
```

Comment: when `duplicated` gets `z$id` it already a mere vector, `R` no longer knows that it is sorted.

Comment: I ran some lines of code. To me length(unique()) does not seem to take quadratic time when the vector is sorted. I suspect there are checks like is.sorted() going on inside base functions.

Answer (score 7):

I'll expand my comment as an answer.

`base::unique` (`unique.default`) on vectors uses hash tables and is quite efficient, with average complexity of O(1) - this is very likely to be the general case. The worst case complexity is O(n). But the chances of that happening at each insert/search should be extremely rare - it must be a terrible hash function if it does.

In your question, you've only one key column, and therefore base's unique should be quite efficient. However, on more than one column, `unique.data.frame` is very inefficient - as it coerces all the columns to characters, then pastes them together and then calls `unique.default` on it.

You can use:

```
nrow(unique(z))
```

data.table's `unique` method, by default, provides key columns to its `by` argument. And since we know the data is already sorted, instead of ordering, we use `data.table:::uniqlist` to fetch the indices corresponding to unique rows much more efficiently in `O(n)` as well. It's therefore efficient on any amount of key columns.

However we could add this information as an attribute while setting the key, as it's quite straightforward.

Comment: Nice explanation.  I didn't know `unique.data.frame` pasted all the columns together.  But now I see that in `duplicated` is where it occurs

Comment: So really, `length(data.table:::uniqlist(z))` will the currently-fastest approach, right? And if you decide to implement [FR900](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/900), that'll provide a more kosher way to access that hidden-in-the-namespace functionality.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, the fastest approach would be to retrieve the attribute  (that can be set) while setting the key (as `forderv` already gathers this info). But after that, yes, this'd be the fastest.