# Most efficient way to calculate total number of groups in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

If you have a data.table `dt` with some keys set, how can you calculate the total number of groups most efficiently?

```
> dt = data.table(a=c(1, 2, 2), b=c(1, 1, 2))
> dt
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 2 2
> setkey(dt, a)
> nrow(unique(dt))
2
```

The above solution `nrow(unique(dt))` works, but is probably not very efficient. Is there a faster way?

Comment: what about `nrow(unique(dt,by="a"))`

Comment: if you don't like to use nrow then maybe this one: `sum(!duplicated(dt, by="a"))`

Comment: @Mahdi Jadaliha: You don't need to specify the "by" argument if you want to use the keys for grouping. From the documentation "by ... Defaults to key(x))". So this is equivalent to what I wrote above.

Comment: You want the total number of groups only in `a` column?

Comment: @Mahdi Jadaliha: You are right, using duplicated should be faster (and again, you don't need "by" if the keys are set). Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26593853/559784)? Please add an issue on the project page.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a duplicate. Thanks for finding that question!

Comment: @Geza: set key sort data.table by the key. I did not want to change the original data.table. I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me describe a little bit why `sum(!duplicated(dt))` is faster:
when you use `nrow(unique(dt))`, you need to make `unique(dt)` table first, however to make this table you need to compute `!duplicated(dt)` first.

when you use `sum(!duplicated(dt))`, there is no need to make `unique(dt)`. (you save some time here!)

but these are not fastest method yet.

here is a faster way to do. Use just the column that you are looking as key:

```
> system.time((for (i in 1:1000) uk = nrow(unique(dt))))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.09    0.00    3.11 
> system.time((for (i in 1:1000) uk = sum(!duplicated(dt))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.63    0.00    0.63 
> system.time((for (i in 1:1000) uk = sum(!duplicated(dt$a))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.24    0.00    0.24
```

if you have several column as key, then it is much easier to use `sum(!duplicated(dt))`. However still it is possible to combine all key columns together with a `paste` function to make a long key instead of all key columns.

**Note that my data.table are much wider than what you used in your analysis, therefore the speed is more distinguishable.**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Mahdi Jadaliha, I compared two solutions on a data.table of dimensions 11811 * 10, with 4 keys, and 2284 unique key combinations. Somewhat unsurprisingly, `sum(!duplicated(dt))` is slightly more efficient than `nrow(unique(dt))`.

```
> system.time((for (i in 1:10000) uk = nrow(unique(dt))))
   user  system elapsed 
 38.037   0.728  38.707 
> system.time((for (i in 1:10000) uk = sum(!duplicated(dt))))
   user  system elapsed 
 29.154   0.723  29.872 
> dim(dt)
[1] 11811    10
> length(key(dt))
[1] 4
> uk
[1] 2284
```